# Not born, but from a Mother's body drawn, who am I?

Tags: riddle

Not born, but from a Mother's body drawn,

I hang until half of me is gone.

I sleep in a cave until I grow old,

then valued for my hardened gold.

Who am I ?

Comment: The first line was such perfect iambic pentameter, then the next lines just totally ruined it. :(

Comment: As this question appears to have been copied from elsewhere, could you please cite your source? For more information, please read [our policy on plagiarism.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/a-policy-on-plagiarism) Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like it's

> Ripe cheese

Not born, but from a Mother's body drawn,

> From a mother's body, it's made of milk

I hang until half of me is gone.

> Milk is kept at rest to separate its different components

I sleep in a cave until I grow old,

> Cheese is left aging in cellars or similar environments

then valued for my hardened gold.

> When it's well aged, the hard crust it develops assumes a yellow-golden color, and the cheese is valued way more than fresh cheese

Comment: I apologize for any imprecisions in the language, but I'm not an english native speaker so some sectorial words elude me :)

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: Now suddenly I'm hungry... Well done. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> A potato.

These come from mother nature, their vines hang and then are disposed of while the main body lives in a cave underground and then they become gold. yukon gold

Answer (score -1):

> Marijuana

mother plants produce the ganja.....
after harvest, the flowers are hung until they are dry and lose half their weight....
when curing, the buds are kept in sealed jars out of sunlight....
and the final perfect nug of weed is hardened and treated like gold (hash)